# JEP library with BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I'm using the third-party library `org.nfunk.jep`. All calculations are in `double` within the library, regardless of which type the input variables had. So when the next code executes:

```
BigDecimal value1 = new BigDecimal("29250.24");
BigDecimal value2 = new BigDecimal("263.21");
JEP calc = new JEP();
calc.addVariable("var1", Double.parseDouble(value1));
calc.addVariable("var2", Double.parseDouble(value2));
calc.parseExpression("var1 - var2");
System.out.println("Result: " + calc.getValue());
```

I want result like "28987.03", but I get such a result:

> Result: 28987.0300000002

Maybe someone knows how to work with this library in `BigDecimal` or knows some similar libraries that work with `BigDecimal` type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a repair:

```
BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(calc.getValue()).setScale(value1.getScale());
```

One can take the resulting double and again place it in a BigDecimal. Special case: the scale for a multiplication would be the sum of the scales of both factors `(0.1 * 0.1 = 0.01)`.

A solution:

Use the [Java Scripting API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/api.html). It exists for several languages, but the Java SE provides a JavaScript scripting which might suffice.

```
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn");

    engine.put("var1", new BigDecimal("3.14"));

    try {
        engine.eval("print(var1.multiply(var1))");
        BigDecimal x = (BigDecimal) engine.eval("var1.multiply(var1)");
        double y = (Double) engine.eval("var1 * var1");
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's really good to learn new things from experienced people around.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems to be what I looked for.

Answer (score 1):

You can try formatting the number like this:

```
        NumberFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
        System.out.println(numberFormat.format(calc.getValue()));
```

Since, `calc.getValue()` is a double value, this will always format it to 2 decimal places.

I do not know what is your use case of using JEP but simple subtraction can be handled by `BigDecimal` directly.

```
        BigDecimal value1 = new BigDecimal("29250.24");
        BigDecimal value2 = new BigDecimal("263.21");
        System.out.println(value1.subtract(value2)); //28987.03
```

You can read more about it [BigDecimal#subtract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#subtract(java.math.BigDecimal))

Comment: Yes, so I can get exact output, but I want exact calculation, without calculating error.

Comment: `numberFormat.format()` will round off the number. e.g. `28987.0390000002` will be formatted to `28987.04`

What do you mean `without calculating error`?

Comment: I mean 29250.24-263.21=28987.03, not 28987.0300000002. This error occurs due to `double` type.

Comment: @Ksenia please read updated answer. You can go directly with `BigDecimal` as well.